# Determine which button was pressed using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Say that I have three "button" elements in one parent "div". Assuming that these buttons could be labeled 1, 2, 3 or 0, 1, 2, using jQuery, is there an easy way to determine the number of which button is clicked?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="table-tabs">
    <button class="tab1 selected">Description</button>
    <button class="tab2">Monitoring</button>
    <button class="tab3">Change Logs</button>
</div>
```

I would like to know the number so that I can activate the appropriate table when a button is pressed.

Comment: show us the intended html and we can show you

Comment: Yes there is.  What does the HTML look like, what does your JavaScript look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.index()` to get the number of the button (staring at 0).

```
$('.table-tabs button').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index('.table-tabs button'));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UPKgm/

Or, you can parse the `class` and get the tab number, but that takes more work.

```
$('.table-tabs button').click(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' '),
        tabID;
    $.each(classes, function() {
        if (this.indexOf('tab') === 0) {
            tabID = this.replace('tab', '');
            return false;
        }
    });
    console.log(tabID);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UPKgm/1/

Comment: That's it! Perfect! I know there was something simple like that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.table-tabs button').click(function(){

var btn = $(this).html();

alert(btn);

});
```

Comment: This actually is a great solution since I am essentially using the buttons as tabs and not as form elements. Ideally though, I don't want to store the numbers as values of the button because that attribute may be necessary for form related data.

Answer (score 0):

Just capture which button is clicked. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/MetalFrog/9dDy9/5/

**Edit:** Updated to match your example HTML.

```
$(function(){
    $('.table-tabs button').click( function(){
       console.log( $(this).text() );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.  `<buttons>` don't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: @Rocket hence the change to text. :) Forgot to hit update on the fiddle before grabbing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an input of type button, where the number is set to the value of the input,
you can use a jQuery selector to select all inputs of type button, and then add a function for the click event that will read the value:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="2" />
    <input type="button" value="3" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(":input[type='button']").click(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
)
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/M6v5b/